# Sequencing the order of stages in multiple pipelines in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I have microserviced monorepo in Azure Devops, with pipeline for each of the nested services.

```
root
  /app1/app1-pipeline.yml
  /app2/app2-pipeline.yml
  /app3/app3-pipeline.yml
```

Each of the pipelines has 2 stages:

1. For building and pushing docker images
2. Checkout to another repository, running py script and git pushing output (with metadata).

When for example 3 of the pipelines are triggered by the same commit , I can see that the order of execution of stages is the following:

1. App1 - stage 1
2. App2 - stage 1
3. App3 - stage 1
4. App1 - stage 2
5. App2 - stage 2
6. App3 - stage 2

I am looking for a way to "force" the order of execution to the following:

1. App1 - stage 1
2. App1 - stage 2
3. App2 - stage 1
4. App2 - stage 2
5. App3 - stage 1
6. App3 - stage 2

In other words I want the runner to sequentially execute the pipelines one by one, instead of mixing them.

I couldn't find a solution for it.

Is this possible or maybe it is not recommended(why)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at Pipeline Triggers? They can be used to trigger a pipeline to run when another completes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops#configure-pipeline-resource-triggers

Comment: Yes, I checked it, but it is not a solution in this scenario. I need all of the pipelines to be able to run as standalones as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If multiple pipelines are triggered simultaneously, it is not possible to order the runs of stages like as you require.

---

for your case, as a workaround, you can consider the method like as below:

1. Within each pipeline, you can use the '**`dependsOn`**' key to order the runs of stages.

   ```yaml
   # Stage 2 will run after stage 1 complete.
   # By default, stage 1 should complete successfully.
   stages:
   - stage: 1
     . . .

   - stage: 2
     dependsOn: 1
     . . .
   ```
2. To order the runs of pipelines, you can use pipeline resource trigger ([**Pipeline completion triggers**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops)).

   - In pipeline for App2, set the configuration like as below.

     ```yaml
     trigger: none # Disable CI trigger.
     resources:
        pipelines:
        - pipeline: App1
          source: App1 # Actual name of the pipeline for App1.
          trigger: true
     ```
   - Similar, in pipeline for App3, set the configuration like as below.

     ```yaml
     trigger: none # Disable CI trigger.
     resources:
        pipelines:
        - pipeline: App2
          source: App2 # Actual name of the pipeline for App2.
          trigger: true
     ```

With above configurations, the stages will run following the order like as you expect.

---

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! 
The resource trigger would not work in my case. Because if change is commited only in  /app2/ for example, it will not trigger the pipeline for this microservice.
I guess what I was looking for is not possible , as you have mentioned in your first sentence.